# Adding QGIS feature, that shows coordinates and scale, into a custom application

Tags: pyqgis, coordinates

I'm writing a standalone application using PyQGIS and I'd like to add the QGIS feature that shows coordinates and scale as the cursor hovers over the map.

[image: something like this]

I need to know this mainly in case of raster maps.

Can someone guide me?

Comment: You could try looking at the source code for the [Coordinate Capture tool](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/src/plugins/coordinate_capture). The plugin itself allows users to [point-click to obtain coordinates or use mouse-tracking](http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_coordinate_capture.html) etc.

Comment: Thanks @Joseph, I actually managed to do it using signals, similar to the answer below.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to replicate the status bar shown in the image, do this:

1. Add a QMainWindow in Qt-Designer. A QStatusBar is added by default.
2. Add widgets (2 QLabel) to the status bar in your Python class:

   ```
   self.lblXY = QLabel()
   self.lblXY.setFrameStyle( QFrame.Box )
   self.lblXY.setMinimumWidth( 170 )
   self.lblXY.setAlignment( Qt.AlignCenter )
   self.statusbar.setSizeGripEnabled( False )
   self.statusbar.addPermanentWidget( self.lblXY, 0 )

   self.lblScale = QLabel()
   self.lblScale.setFrameStyle( QFrame.StyledPanel )
   self.lblScale.setMinimumWidth( 140 )
   self.statusbar.addPermanentWidget( self.lblScale, 0 )
   ```
3. Make SIGNALS/SLOTS connections:

   ```
    self.connect( self.canvas, SIGNAL( "xyCoordinates(QgsPoint)" ),
       self.showXY )
    self.connect( self.canvas, SIGNAL( "scaleChanged(double)" ),
       self.showScale )
   ```
4. Define your slots:

   ```
   def showXY( self, p ):
       """ SLOT. Show coordinates """
       self.lblXY.setText( str(p.x()) + " | " + str(p.y()) ) 

   def showScale( self, scale ):
       """ SLOT. Show scale """
       self.lblScale.setText( "Scale 1:" + scale )
   ```

That's it! You'll end up with something like this:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I did - it took me a while, but I figured it out yesterday. Thank you!